How do I move a link to the right inside a "div" tag?
I'm trying to create a menu in my site, and I want to put the "quit" to the right, while the other links are in the left, however I simply can't make it work.
I'm trying to use class for the <a> tag, inside a <div>, already tried creating a second <div>, however it makes the link go to the next line, and I don't want that.
My code:


.right {   
    text-align:right;
}
<div class="meio">
    <p class="paragraf">
        <a href="/php_01/">menu</a> 
        <a class="right" href="/PHP2024_01/">quit</a>
    </p>
</div> 



I have no idea what I did wrong, and I've spent almost 2 hours trying to solve it.

This is where display: flex comes in handy. Here's a simple way to use it for this purpose:


.paragraf {display: flex;}
.right {margin-left: auto;}
<div class="meio">
  <p class="paragraf">
    <a href="/php_01/">menu</a> 
    <a class="right" href="/PHP2024_01/">quit</a>
  </p>
</div> 




Parent elements take precedence over child elements, hence text-align doesn't work on the a-element. You'd have to put the link in a separate paragraph and apply the text-align on the paragraph. However, you could use float:
.right {   
  float:right;
}

This could mess up other parts of your code however, so use with 'caution'.

In this case, the best solution is to use flexbox so here is the solution:
p.paragraf {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}


this is how to make two elements in different spaces one on the left and the other on the right



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .paragraf{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="meio">
        <p class="paragraf">
            <a href="/php_01/">menu</a> 
            <a class="right" href="/PHP2024_01/">quit</a>
        </p>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>



Setting display of parent class to flex and then adding a property justify-content: spacebetween will add sspaces between the child elements. Using flexbox is easy way to achieve this kind of structure.
